# Trying to use Terragrunt (terraform) with Okta

Tags: terraform, okta, terragrunt

I am trying to leverage the use of Okta in Terragrunt and I am encoutering issues when assuming the role.
My ~/.aws/config file

```
aws_saml_url = home/amazon_aws/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX

[profile assume-admin]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/assumeAdmin
region = us-west-2

[profile dev]
source_profile = assume-admin
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/adminUser
```

Without terragrunt, using only Terraform and Okta, I don't see any issue.

```
$ aws-okta exec dev -- bash
$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.terraform_remote_state.bastion: Refreshing state...
data.terraform_remote_state.vpc: Refreshing state...
data.terraform_remote_state.bastion: Refreshing state...
data.terraform_remote_state.vpc: Refreshing state...
data.aws_caller_identity.current: Refreshing state...

SNIP

Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

Now using Terragrunt

```
terragrunt plan
[terragrunt] [/Users/user/dev/infrastructure/terraform/accounts/dev/us-west-2/dev/app] 2018/07/23 17:32:56 Running command: terraform --version
[terragrunt] 2018/07/23 17:32:56 Reading Terragrunt config file at /Users/user/dev/infrastructure/terraform/accounts/dev/us-west-2/dev/app/terraform.tfvars
[terragrunt] 2018/07/23 17:32:56 Backend s3 has not changed.
[terragrunt] 2018/07/23 17:32:56 Error initializing session: SharedConfigAssumeRoleError: failed to load assume role for arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/adminUser, source profile has no shared credentials
[terragrunt] 2018/07/23 17:32:56 Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by setting `AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/dev/null` after executing `aws-okta exec takt-dev -- bash`, which loaded my AWS_* creds/variables.

Using `AWS_PROFILE=PROFILE_NAME` or having the shell variables undefined with `unset AWS_*` would return the error i mentioned above.

FYI. I'm running Terraform v0.11.7